# Azure B2C - Remove change email button from verification step

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Does anyone know how to skip 'change email' step from verification steps by using custom policy?

[Change email step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Watit.png)

Comment: User flows => Page Layouts => Here use custom html pages for the selfAsserted cases (Forgot / Change password). In the custom html add the required style.

Question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69509093/adjust-email-verification-user-interface-in-azureb2c-custom-policies

Answer (score 3):

The only way is to use CSS to hide the element.