# B2C-Unable to remove email verification step

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I used this [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69509093/adjust-email-verification-user-interface-in-azureb2c-custom-policies) to split my signup process.
I need to remove the 3rd page of email validation. The same question was asked in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69509093/adjust-email-verification-user-interface-in-azureb2c-custom-policies), I tried the same solution but it only hide the change email button, but not skip the page entirely.

**HTML code :**

```
<button class="editButton" id="email_ver_but_edit" type="button" aria-label="Change e-mail" style="display: inline;" aria-hidden="false">Change e-mail</button>
```

**CSS code :**

```
#email_ver_but_edit {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

***PS:** Continue and cancel buttons are also hided, I just need to show them in the last page.*

[image]

Comment: Do you want to auto submit the page once email is verified?

Comment: After code validation, I need to skip the 3rd page and load the last one wich contain readOnly email, password...
Is this possible? the same need was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69509093/adjust-email-verification-user-interface-in-azureb2c-custom-policies)